# Is it possible to intrinsically prove $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete/not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, curves

I was having a discussion with some colleagues and the topic of whether or not the universe is continuous/discrete came up: we all came to the same conclusion that no matter the situation, we'll never be able to know for sure (because to prove it one way or the other would require having measurements of infinite precision, which is impossible). A colleague gave a rough/informal example of this: he claimed an observer living entirely within $\mathbb{N}$ (imagine the same picture we have for surfaces of an ant walking along the surface, but for $\mathbb{N}$ instead) could never prove his universe to be discrete.

We, habitants of $\geq 3$ dimensional space, naturally know $\mathbb{N}$ *is* discrete and consists entirely of totally isolated points. I thought about it for a while and all the ways we can usually prove $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete cannot be turned into "experiments" an observer living entirely inside $\mathbb{N}$ could perform (for example, an observer living in the space $\mathbb{S}^1$ could perform the experiment of walking around a finite distance in a finite amount of time and see they have returned to the same starting place, thus carrying out an intrinsic proof that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$).

Now, I realize this is all a bit meaningless since I for one don't see how an observer living entirely within $\mathbb{N}$ could *ever* leave his starting place to begin with (since all points of $\mathbb{N}$ are totally isolated). But for argument's sake, please dismiss this hurdle. To give a more formalized and tractable version of the problem, consider $\mathbb{N}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $$\mathbb{N} \times \{(0,0) \} = \{ (n, 0, 0) \ \vert\  n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Is there any experiment a habitant of this space could perform to prove that his universe is discrete (say, not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ seen as the line $\{(t, 0, 0) \ \vert \ t \in \mathbb{R}\}$)?

Comment: This is an interesting question but I think the biggest issue with answering it is that you don't define what you mean by an 'experiment'. One 'experiment' you could perform is to mark 2 points and see if you can always find point between them and keep repeating this, if you can't you are in an discrete ordered space and the longer you can do it the more confidence you have that you are not in a discrete space, but now as no definition of 'experiment' is given I don't know what result you would get or if this counts as a valid answer.

Comment: This is not a mathematical question.

Comment: @Fishbane thanks for the comment! I find it hard to come up with a concrete definition of what an "experiment" would be, it's really only an intuitive idea, but it would be great if someone else thought about a way of formalizing it. Your idea is pretty good but still, confidence is all it gives (since an observer cannot perform infinitely many experiments), I was looking for a concrete proof

Comment: @RobArthan I disagree.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Actually it can be used to prove you are in a discrete space, it just can't be used to determine if you are in one. What I mean is that you can run it and if you are in a discrete space it will terminate at some point, so if you are certain you are in a discrete space but desire proof you can run the experiment and wait for it to terminate.

Comment: @Fishbane Ah, I see what you meant. But I'm not convinced this counts as an experiment, because I don't see how an observer could prove the non existence of points between two given points

Comment: We can't perform experiments in the natural numbers or the real numbers or (whatever we might think comprise) the numbers that "exist" in our universe (a meaningless notion, in my opinion). So this is not a mathematical question.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Hence my point about the lack of definition of 'experiment'. I or someone else could keep coming up with more elaborate things but you can essentially keep saying you don't think it counts. That isn't to say it is a bad idea of a question but to make it a maths question we need some definition to work from otherwise it is essentially philosophy. I suggest asking on a philosophy stack exchange as they are better at answering questions like these and possibly it is already an explored idea. (I'm not a philosopher so I don't know about that)

Comment: @MatheusAndrade If you want a guess at what we might define as an experiment, a good starting point might be a first order formula which is true in $\left(\Bbb{R},\leq\right)$ but not in $\left(\Bbb{N},\leq\right)$ as this captures some of the desired finiteness properties. EDIT (Actually I think this would permit my 'experiment' so maybe it isn't a good start for what you want)

Comment: I've always thought that the most important characteristic of $\mathbb{N}$ is that two distinct elements are at least $1$ apart.

Comment: @martycohen While true (enough) this doesn't help with the idea behind the question. Specifically you can think of this question as being about how you find '1'. For example suppose a distance of 1 meter is equivalent to some unimaginable large number, then you would still be in $\Bbb{N}$ but there would be many points less than 1 meter apart. The 'experiment' I gave explains how to find '1'.

Comment: @martycohen thanks! This is painfully obvious, I should've thought of it sooner.

Comment: @Fishbane you are right, your idea is a little better. The observer inside $\mathbb{N}$ has no way of proving $1$ is smallest real number such that $d(x, y) \geq 1$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$, so this doesn't count as an experiment either in the end

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Ultimately I think an answer can be summerized as follows. If there is no method by which you can test if there is a point between 2 points clearly we cannot distinguish $\Bbb{N}$ and $\Bbb{R}$ as I could just 'hide' all the points other than natural numbers in $\Bbb{R}$. Otherwise if we can test for the existance of a point between 2 points and also can find such a point if one exists then my method allows you to prove you are in $\Bbb{N}$ (althogh it doesn't help you determine if you are).

Comment: @Fishbane your remark has been very helpful. Thanks! I guess this is as good of an answer as I can expect. If you want to summarize your comments into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade I would actualy personally prefer not to add an answer as I don't like giving answers that I feel are incomplete. However it is good to have an accepted answer so that this question is properly resolved so if you are happy with what I have said you are free to write your interpretation of what I have said up as an answer yourself and then accept that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the world is not such and such, it's our models of the world that are such and such. But of course some models are more graceful than others so they are preferred. As an example, the 19th century concept of ether as the propagation medium for light, was discarded because it brought nothing and was complex to explain, not because it could be possible to disprove it. Similarly, there are some deterministic interpretations of quantum theory, but they are not mainstream because they bring nothing more and are more complex.

If the world - or, more exactly, our experiments results - are correctly explained by a theory with a continuous space, assuming it uses only space-continuous variables you can always make a discrete-space theory that gives the same results, with a sufficiently finely grained space. Under the assumption that our experiments have a limited precision, of course.

Reciprocally, if our experiments are correctly explained by a discrete-space theory, you can always invent a continuous-space theory and say the space is filled with a grid of particles that explain the seemingly discrete results. (Actually the Higgs Boson looks somewhat like that kind of particle - but I am not a physicist at all). Or use any math model that generates discrete phenomena despite the space being continuous (e.g. eigenvalues). Whether such a theory would be graceful enough to survive is not obvious, so perhaps in that case the discrete nature of space would be considered proven.

Comment: "the world is not such and such"... surely the world is either continuous (in the sense asked by OP), or it is not continuous? I don't see a third option.

Comment: @afreelunch We observe the world through experiments. Then we model the experiment results through theories. Usually there are plenty of theories that predict the same results, and our choice between theories is somewhat subjective, or based on simplicity principles such as Occam's razor. And it seems to me that you can propose both continuous-space and discrete-space theories that make the same predictions, for the reasons I give above.